# Retrieve facebook user id from the username

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to retrieve a Facebook user id if I have his username.
This was deprecated from the graph API but I would like to know a work around on getting the id if i have the username.

There is a [website](http://findmyfbid.com) that does that but I am not sure how they do it.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg in that case OPs questions is offtopic as it's asking of off page software.

Comment: @DocRattie He is just asking a question. If you don't have the ans then leave it. Don't try to be "rude or offensive".

Comment: @V.J. I neither try to be rude nor to be offensive. But it's offtopic to ask for off page software on SO.

Comment: He is asking that is it possible or not. 
Your answer must be like this. "No, this is not possible".
Simple.

Comment: @DocRattie : way to go !!! deleting the rude and offensive comment ! A bit of common-sense with the 'rules and regs' and courtesy go a long way towards the value of SO. The question is valid IMO because every other answer here states it cant be done, yet this website succeeds !

Comment: @YvesLeBorg dude, I didn't delete any comments. But maybe you flaged it and it got deleted due to that.

Comment: @V.J. Does he at any point ask "If it's possible" ? They way I understand it he stat's that it's possible and that there is a page that does it. Therefore I understand it the way that OP want's to know "How it's possible" and that means asking for their code.

Comment: I am dying to know that how that site makes it possible.
Because facebook and its graph api does not provide anything to fetch userid from username.

Comment: @V.J. you will get a hint if you show `source` in your developer tools.

Comment: Yes i got the hint.

Open https://facebook.com/username in browser.
see the html code.

find "<meta property="al:android:url" content="fb://profile/100006480074833">" this tag. It is with all the facebook username.

Comment: That's great guys, that's what i was looking for, i thought of the source code first but never knew it might show in the source code.

Comment: @user3010296 i have posted the answer to find the userid from username without using api. Please check it. Its a c# code.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Check my answer. I did it. Not 100%. But 90-92%.

Answer (score 4):

I did the R&D and found that the given website is not using the API to fetch userid from the username. 
They are using another mechanism which is not valid.

I have found 1 mechanism to find the userid from the username.

Below is the c# code which identify how to find userid from username.
I tried to read the HTML from facebook url. and trying to read below meta tag to identify userid.

**META Code**

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="fb://profile/USERID">
```

**Function**

```
public string findUserIdfromUsername(string facebookURL)
{
    try
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(facebookURL);

        List<String> keyLst = doc.DocumentNode
                                .SelectSingleNode("//meta[@property='al:android:url']")
                                .Attributes["content"].Value
                                .Split(',').ToList();


        foreach (string strkey in keyLst)
        {
            string[] arrTemp = strkey.Split('/');
            int arrlength = arrTemp.Count();
            string facebookUserID = arrlength > 0 ? (arrTemp[arrlength - 1]) : strkey;
            facebookUserID = facebookUserID.Replace("?id=", "");
            return facebookUserID;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 

    }
    return "";
}
```

**Requirement**

1. I have used "HtmlAgilityPack.dll" to load the html and parse it like XML.
2. To test call the function like below.
   findUserIdfromUsername("https://facebook.com/USERNAME");
3. I have only test 3-4 urls and getting right userid.
4. I am not using any API to find USERID.
5. My English and steps are not too much good. So please manage it.

Comment: Ok. After that please post your ans for the PHP.

Comment: I am almost done with the code. But i am not able to right the code that matches the pattern :
<meta property="al:android:url" content="fb://profile/123123121123" />
using preg_match_all();

it needs to be something like this : 
 //        preg_match_all('<meta property="al:android:url" content="fb://profile/121312312312123" />', $like_html, $matches);

Comment: I am not familiar with php. So not able to help you in this case. Sorry dude.